# google chart stops page scroling

Tags: php, charts, scroll

I am trying to draw some google charts. I get my data from mysql database and I am using this class  ( https://code.google.com/p/php-class-for-google-chart-tools/ ) to convert php variables to jquery variables (this class uses JSON I think).

Charts work great, but when they load, I can't scroll the page. I tried to set inline css on body element height:2000px. While charts are loading i can scroll the page without any problem, but at the moment, when the first chart is loaded, the page stops at one place and I cant scroll up or down anymore.

Can it be some focus problem?

How should I solve this problem?

```
<body style="height:2000px;background-color:yellow;"> - body element with height 2000px

$chart = new Chart('ComboChart'); - creating new instance of chart class

for($i=1;$i<=$num_of_questions;$i++){

    echo "<div id='chart_div".$i."'></div>";
    $num_of_divs++;
}

$used_divs = 0;
```

here I create divs for google charts

```
$chart->load($data, 'array');
$options = array('title' => $otazky['otazka'],  'seriesType' => bars,'width' => 700, 'height'      =>250);
$used_divs++;
$div = 'chart_div'.$used_divs;
echo $chart->draw($div, $options);
```

Comment: Can you please show couple of code? We are not mind readers.

Comment: Done :) Can u help me now ? :/

Comment: i hope in your real code `- creating new instance of chart class` this doesnt exists.

Comment: also did you close `</body>` tag end of your dom?

Comment: and could you please use `var_dump` your php data part and make a fiddle without php so we can understand which part fails, php or html.

Comment: fiddle without php ? PHP class draws the charts here is a link to class witch I use https://code.google.com/p/php-class-for-google-chart-tools/ . Of course - creating new ... isn't exist in code :D and yes, the body tag is closed. Here is var_dump and print_r of $data

Comment: array(10) { [0]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(6) "Mesiac" [1]=> string(2) "tv" [2]=> string(8) "internet" [3]=> string(10) "chladnicku" [4]=> string(5) "lampu" } [1]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(3) "jan" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL [3]=> NULL [4]=> NULL } [2]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(3) "feb" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL [3]=> NULL [4]=> NULL } [3]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(3) "mar" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL [3]=>

Comment: NULL [4]=> NULL } [4]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(3) "apr" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL [3]=> NULL [4]=> NULL } [5]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(4) "máj" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL [3]=> NULL [4]=> NULL } [6]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(4) "jún" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL [3]=> NULL [4]=> NULL } [7]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(4) "júl" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL [3]=> NULL [4]=> NULL } [8]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(3) "aug" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL [3]=> NULL [4]=> NULL } [9]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(3) "sep" [1]=> int(1) [2]=> int(1) [3]=> NULL [4]=> NULL     } }

Comment: there is some jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/f0aho7wh/

Comment: All of your values Null?

Comment: Not all, At the last line, for mount september there are value and there are some values for march too. The graph works with no problem, just the scrolling...

Comment: I'm off, dont understand what is wrong.

Comment: lets try it and you will understand www.login.kvalitasluzieb.sk

login is : brezany.m@gmail.com
pass : Yy5uEG

click on ''zobraziť grafy''

and try to scroll before the chart is loaded and after the chart is loaded. 

I don't know why I didn't put this here like this :D Hope you will understand.